# OAuth Instagram API remove parameter in redirect URL when connect Instagram without logged in browser

Tags: oauth, instagram, redirect, instagram-api

The Instagram API (classic, not graph) loses the custom parameter in the redirect URL, if user try login in OAuth window.

Because of losing the custom parameter in the redirect URI, Instagram fetching access token is returning "Redirect URI not matching error"

Response from Instagram :

```
{'error_code'=>90001, 'error_message'=>'POST https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token/: 400: OAuthException: Redirect URI doesn't match original redirect URI'}
```

Everything works fine if the user is logged in Instagram before doing OAuth.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read the [ask] page and update your question.

Comment: Having the same issue. Drops the value of the parameter in redirecturl.

Comment: I am also seeing the same issue from the recent past

Comment: The redirect URL must match what you registered. Why do you need a custom parameter? What OS or platform are you on? It's generally easy to track the whole progress of the authentication and therefore not need parameters. I do Instagram Auth quite a bit.

Comment: Any updates or workaround about this?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the uri for fetching the token to the broken redirect url you get for the login in OAuth window. This will give a proper response. But offcourse you will lose your queryparameter.

You can always add a specific rule in your application by checking if the redirect url you pass on has changed.

this is obviously not a fix but a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but when i tryied to report it the platform say to me "the support was deprecated". The workaround I found was save the parameter/s in the **sessionStorage** on the browser.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried writing to Instagram support? Looks like Instagram's bug.

Another workaround: you can pass this custom parameter inside parameter `state` (see https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)